# Can I disable unit upgrade from a ruin?

Tags: civilization-5

I dislike the "Advanced weaponry" ruins perk that upgrades your unit. Is there anyway via a mod or custom configuration to disable it and leave the other ruin perks intact?

Comment: Personally, I love having archers that can move two hexes through forests. They can mow down barbs with ease.

Answer (score 5):

You can edit the game files to remove this specific Ancient Ruins reward.

The data for the rewards is in a file called CIV5GoodyHuts.xml in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Sid Meier's Civilization V\Assets\Gameplay\XML\GameInfo
```

Before making any edits, I suggest you make a backup. Then open the file in notepad/other text editor and remove the following values:

```
<Column name="UpgradeUnit" type="boolean" default="false"/>
```

and:

```
<Row>
        <Type>GOODY_UPGRADE_UNIT</Type>
        <Description>TXT_KEY_GOODY_UPGRADE_UNIT</Description>
        <Sound/>
        <UpgradeUnit>true</UpgradeUnit>
    </Row>
```

Comment: Seemed like a good plan, but did not work.

Comment: Separate from the other answer, I have only recommend against removing the `<Column>` definition since code may try to read it, and I don't know how forgiving of removed columns the system is. The rest should be okay.

Answer (score 1):

shanondin's answer was helpful but didn't fully solve the problem. Starting from their solution I was able to find other places where the upgrade was referenced.

Rather than delete the reference in the XML file I opted to learn the mod tools and alter the game that way.

The mod I created is available in the steam workshop [here](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=316085773). The zip file for the mod is attached to this [forum post](http://forums.civfanatics.com/showpost.php?p=13463059&postcount=3).